# Multitasking with Arduino?

Tags: led, arduino-pro-mini, piezo

I am making a Christmas Tree with Arduino. I found a 12 led chaser code on internet so I made 12 rows of leds and hook them up to my Arduino pro mini.
They are working just fine.

However, I also want to add music with piezo buzzer while running the LEDs. Is that possible somehow or should I use another microcontroller for piezo? I also used pin 10 for piezo buzzer and used pin 14(a0) for led assigned for pin 10 previously..

Here are the codes:
12 led chaser

```cpp
#define t   30
#define t1  20
#define t2  100
#define t3  50

void setup() {
  // set up pins 2 to 13 as outputs
  for (int i = 2; i <= 13; i++) {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Effect 1
void loop(){

effect_1();
effect_1();

 effect_2();
 effect_2();

 effect_3();
 effect_3();

 effect_4();
 effect_4();

 effect_5();
 effect_5();

 effect_6();
 effect_6();

 effect_7();
 effect_7();
  }
//left to right and right to left
void effect_1()
{
for(int i=2; i<14; i++){
digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
delay(t1);
digitalWrite(i+1, HIGH);
delay(t1);
digitalWrite(i+2, HIGH);
delay(t1);
digitalWrite(i, LOW);
delay(t1);
digitalWrite(i+1, LOW);
delay(t1);
}
for(int i=13; i>1; i--){
digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
delay(t1);
digitalWrite(i-1, HIGH);
delay(t1);
digitalWrite(i-2, HIGH);
delay(t1);
digitalWrite(i, LOW);
delay(t1);
digitalWrite(i-1, LOW);
delay(t1);
}
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Effect 2
void effect_2()
{
int count = 13; // keeps track of second LED movement

  // move first LED from left to right and second from right to left
  for (int i = 2; i < 13; i++) {
    clear();
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);      // chaser 1
    digitalWrite(count, HIGH); // chaser 2
    count--;
    // stop LEDs from appearing to stand still in the middle
    if (count != 7) {
      delay(t2);
    }
  }

  // move first LED from right to left and second LED from left to right
  for (int i = 13; i > 2; i--) {
    clear();
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);      // chaser 1
    digitalWrite(count, HIGH); // chaser 2
    count++;
    // stop LEDs from appearing to stand still in the middle
    if (count != 8) {
      delay(t2);
    }
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Effect 3

void effect_3()
{
for(int i=2; i<14; i++){
  digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
  delay(t3);
}
for(int i=2; i<14; i++){
  digitalWrite(i, LOW);
  delay(t3);
}


for(int i = 14; i>=2; i--){
  digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
  delay(t3);
}
for(int i = 14; i>=2; i--){
  digitalWrite(i, LOW);
  delay(t3);
}
}
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Effect 4
void effect_4()
{
for(int j = 2; j <= 13; j++){
  digitalWrite(j, HIGH);
  delay(t2);
  j=j+1;
  }
for(int j = 2; j <= 13; j++){
  digitalWrite(j, LOW);
  delay(t2);
  }

  for(int k = 15; k > 2; k--){
  digitalWrite(k, HIGH);
  delay(t2);
  k=k-1;
  }
for(int k = 15; k > 2; k--){
  digitalWrite(k, LOW);
  delay(t2);
  }
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Effect 5
  void effect_5()
{
 for(int pin = 13; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
  digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
  delay(t1);
  digitalWrite(pin+1, LOW);
  delay(t1);
  }
  for(int pin = 13; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
  digitalWrite(pin+1, HIGH);
  delay(t1);
  digitalWrite(pin+2, LOW);
  delay(t1);
  }
  for(int pin = 13; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
  digitalWrite(pin+2, HIGH);
  delay(t1);
  digitalWrite(pin+3, LOW);
  delay(t1);
  }
  for(int pin = 13; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
  digitalWrite(pin+3, HIGH);
  delay(t1);
  digitalWrite(pin+4, LOW);
  delay(t1);
  }
    for(int pin = 13; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
  digitalWrite(pin+4, HIGH);
  delay(t1);
  digitalWrite(pin+5, LOW);
  delay(t1);
  }
  for(int pin = 13; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
  digitalWrite(pin+5, HIGH);
  delay(t1);
  digitalWrite(pin+6, LOW);
  delay(t1);
  }
  for(int pin = 13; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
  digitalWrite(pin+6, HIGH);
  delay(t1);
  digitalWrite(pin+7, LOW);
  delay(t1);
  }
   for(int pin = 13; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
  digitalWrite(pin+7, HIGH);
  delay(t1);
  digitalWrite(pin+8, LOW);
  delay(t1);
  }
  for(int pin = 9; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
  digitalWrite(pin+8, HIGH);
  delay(t1);
  digitalWrite(pin+9, LOW);
  delay(t1);
  }
    for(int pin = 9; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
  digitalWrite(pin+9, HIGH);
  delay(t1);
  digitalWrite(pin+10, LOW);
  delay(t1);
  }
  for(int pin = 9; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
  digitalWrite(pin+10, HIGH);
  delay(t1);
  digitalWrite(pin+11, LOW);
  delay(t1);
  }
  for(int pin = 14; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
  digitalWrite(pin+11, HIGH);
  delay(t1);
  }
  for(int pin = 13; pin >= 2; pin--)
  {
    digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
  delay(t1);
    }
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Effect 6
void effect_6()
{
for(int j=2; j<14; j++){
  digitalWrite(j, LOW);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(j, HIGH);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(j-2, LOW);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(j, HIGH);
}
for(int k = 15; k>2; k--){
  digitalWrite(k, LOW);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k, HIGH);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k+2, LOW);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k, HIGH);
}
for(int k = 2; k<14; k++){
  digitalWrite(k, LOW);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k, HIGH);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k-2, LOW);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k, HIGH);
}
for(int k = 15; k>2; k--){
  digitalWrite(k, LOW);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k, HIGH);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k+4, LOW);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k, HIGH);
}
for(int k = 2; k<14; k++){
  digitalWrite(k, LOW);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k, HIGH);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k-4, LOW);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k, HIGH);
} 
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Effect 7
void effect_7()
{
for(int j=2; j<14; j++){
  digitalWrite(j, HIGH);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(j+2, LOW);
  delay(t);
}
for(int k = 15; k>2; k--){
  digitalWrite(k, HIGH);
  delay(t);
  digitalWrite(k+2, LOW);
  delay(t);
}
}

// function to switch all LEDs off
void clear(void)
{
  for (int i = 2; i <= 13; i++) {
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
  }
}
```

Melody tone for buzzer:

```cpp
/* 
  We Wish You a Merry Christmas - Traditional Christmas song
  Connect a piezo buzzer or speaker to pin 11 or select a new pin.
  More songs available at https://github.com/robsoncouto/arduino-songs                                            
                                              
                                              Robson Couto, 2019
*/
#define NOTE_B0  31
#define NOTE_C1  33
#define NOTE_CS1 35
#define NOTE_D1  37
#define NOTE_DS1 39
#define NOTE_E1  41
#define NOTE_F1  44
#define NOTE_FS1 46
#define NOTE_G1  49
#define NOTE_GS1 52
#define NOTE_A1  55
#define NOTE_AS1 58
#define NOTE_B1  62
#define NOTE_C2  65
#define NOTE_CS2 69
#define NOTE_D2  73
#define NOTE_DS2 78
#define NOTE_E2  82
#define NOTE_F2  87
#define NOTE_FS2 93
#define NOTE_G2  98
#define NOTE_GS2 104
#define NOTE_A2  110
#define NOTE_AS2 117
#define NOTE_B2  123
#define NOTE_C3  131
#define NOTE_CS3 139
#define NOTE_D3  147
#define NOTE_DS3 156
#define NOTE_E3  165
#define NOTE_F3  175
#define NOTE_FS3 185
#define NOTE_G3  196
#define NOTE_GS3 208
#define NOTE_A3  220
#define NOTE_AS3 233
#define NOTE_B3  247
#define NOTE_C4  262
#define NOTE_CS4 277
#define NOTE_D4  294
#define NOTE_DS4 311
#define NOTE_E4  330
#define NOTE_F4  349
#define NOTE_FS4 370
#define NOTE_G4  392
#define NOTE_GS4 415
#define NOTE_A4  440
#define NOTE_AS4 466
#define NOTE_B4  494
#define NOTE_C5  523
#define NOTE_CS5 554
#define NOTE_D5  587
#define NOTE_DS5 622
#define NOTE_E5  659
#define NOTE_F5  698
#define NOTE_FS5 740
#define NOTE_G5  784
#define NOTE_GS5 831
#define NOTE_A5  880
#define NOTE_AS5 932
#define NOTE_B5  988
#define NOTE_C6  1047
#define NOTE_CS6 1109
#define NOTE_D6  1175
#define NOTE_DS6 1245
#define NOTE_E6  1319
#define NOTE_F6  1397
#define NOTE_FS6 1480
#define NOTE_G6  1568
#define NOTE_GS6 1661
#define NOTE_A6  1760
#define NOTE_AS6 1865
#define NOTE_B6  1976
#define NOTE_C7  2093
#define NOTE_CS7 2217
#define NOTE_D7  2349
#define NOTE_DS7 2489
#define NOTE_E7  2637
#define NOTE_F7  2794
#define NOTE_FS7 2960
#define NOTE_G7  3136
#define NOTE_GS7 3322
#define NOTE_A7  3520
#define NOTE_AS7 3729
#define NOTE_B7  3951
#define NOTE_C8  4186
#define NOTE_CS8 4435
#define NOTE_D8  4699
#define NOTE_DS8 4978
#define REST      0


// change this to make the song slower or faster
int tempo = 140;

// change this to whichever pin you want to use
int buzzer = 11;

// notes of the moledy followed by the duration.
// a 4 means a quarter note, 8 an eighteenth , 16 sixteenth, so on
// !!negative numbers are used to represent dotted notes,
// so -4 means a dotted quarter note, that is, a quarter plus an eighteenth!!
int melody[] = {

  // We Wish You a Merry Christmas
  // Score available at https://musescore.com/user/6208766/scores/1497501
  
  NOTE_C5,4, //1
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_F5,8, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_F5,8, NOTE_E5,8,
  NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_D5,4,
  NOTE_G5,4, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_F5,8,
  NOTE_E5,4, NOTE_C5,4, NOTE_C5,4,
  NOTE_A5,4, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_AS5,8, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_G5,8,
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_C5,8, NOTE_C5,8,
  NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_G5,4, NOTE_E5,4,

  NOTE_F5,2, NOTE_C5,4, //8 
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_F5,8, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_F5,8, NOTE_E5,8,
  NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_D5,4,
  NOTE_G5,4, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_F5,8,
  NOTE_E5,4, NOTE_C5,4, NOTE_C5,4,
  NOTE_A5,4, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_AS5,8, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_G5,8,
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_C5,8, NOTE_C5,8,
  NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_G5,4, NOTE_E5,4,
  NOTE_F5,2, NOTE_C5,4,

  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_F5,4,//17
  NOTE_E5,2, NOTE_E5,4,
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_E5,4, NOTE_D5,4,
  NOTE_C5,2, NOTE_A5,4,
  NOTE_AS5,4, NOTE_A5,4, NOTE_G5,4,
  NOTE_C6,4, NOTE_C5,4, NOTE_C5,8, NOTE_C5,8,
  NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_G5,4, NOTE_E5,4,
  NOTE_F5,2, NOTE_C5,4, 
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_F5,8, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_F5,8, NOTE_E5,8,
  NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_D5,4,
  
  NOTE_G5,4, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_F5,8, //27
  NOTE_E5,4, NOTE_C5,4, NOTE_C5,4,
  NOTE_A5,4, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_AS5,8, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_G5,8,
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_C5,8, NOTE_C5,8,
  NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_G5,4, NOTE_E5,4,
  NOTE_F5,2, NOTE_C5,4,
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_F5,4,
  NOTE_E5,2, NOTE_E5,4,
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_E5,4, NOTE_D5,4,
  
  NOTE_C5,2, NOTE_A5,4,//36
  NOTE_AS5,4, NOTE_A5,4, NOTE_G5,4,
  NOTE_C6,4, NOTE_C5,4, NOTE_C5,8, NOTE_C5,8,
  NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_G5,4, NOTE_E5,4,
  NOTE_F5,2, NOTE_C5,4, 
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_F5,8, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_F5,8, NOTE_E5,8,
  NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_D5,4,
  NOTE_G5,4, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_F5,8, 
  NOTE_E5,4, NOTE_C5,4, NOTE_C5,4,
  
  NOTE_A5,4, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_AS5,8, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_G5,8,//45
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_C5,8, NOTE_C5,8,
  NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_G5,4, NOTE_E5,4,
  NOTE_F5,2, NOTE_C5,4,
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_F5,8, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_F5,8, NOTE_E5,8,
  NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_D5,4,
  NOTE_G5,4, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_G5,8, NOTE_F5,8,
  NOTE_E5,4, NOTE_C5,4, NOTE_C5,4,
  
  NOTE_A5,4, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_AS5,8, NOTE_A5,8, NOTE_G5,8, //53
  NOTE_F5,4, NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_C5,8, NOTE_C5,8,
  NOTE_D5,4, NOTE_G5,4, NOTE_E5,4,
  NOTE_F5,2, REST,4
};

// sizeof gives the number of bytes, each int value is composed of two bytes (16 bits)
// there are two values per note (pitch and duration), so for each note there are four bytes
int notes = sizeof(melody) / sizeof(melody[0]) / 2;

// this calculates the duration of a whole note in ms
int wholenote = (60000 * 4) / tempo;

int divider = 0, noteDuration = 0;

void setup() {
  // iterate over the notes of the melody.
  // Remember, the array is twice the number of notes (notes + durations)
  for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < notes * 2; thisNote = thisNote + 2) {

    // calculates the duration of each note
    divider = melody[thisNote + 1];
    if (divider > 0) {
      // regular note, just proceed
      noteDuration = (wholenote) / divider;
    } else if (divider < 0) {
      // dotted notes are represented with negative durations!!
      noteDuration = (wholenote) / abs(divider);
      noteDuration *= 1.5; // increases the duration in half for dotted notes
    }

    // we only play the note for 90% of the duration, leaving 10% as a pause
    tone(buzzer, melody[thisNote], noteDuration * 0.9);

    // Wait for the specief duration before playing the next note.
    delay(noteDuration);

    // stop the waveform generation before the next note.
    noTone(buzzer);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // no need to repeat the melody.
}
```

Comment: Yes, possible. Please look into non-blocking coding styles, like the one demonstrated in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE. It uses `millis()` as a time source, checking regularly, if it is time to do something, otherwise doing something else. There are tons of tutorials on the web about `millis()`. Please try them first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the method suggested by chrisl is probably the best for you to use here.  If you want to make a more-conventional multitasking system, you would set a timer such as TIMER2 to the minimum time slice, then at the start of your code (after setup) you'd have something like this:

ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect)
{
myIntHandler();
}

Here myIntHandler() does whatever needs to get done on each tick of TIMER2.  I use this general approach in my open-source DaqPort code to do simultaneous oscilloscope data acquisition and signal generation, while still handling serial commands in the background.
But that's probably overkill for your project. You can find out more about DaqPort at
https://www.daqarta.com/dw_rraa.htm

Comment: There are a couple of issues with this approach. The first is that it handles tasks in a “run-to-completion” mode, i.e. the tasks have to be defined as non-blocking functions that return after a single step, and keep static state in order to know what to do next time they are called. This makes the code not much simpler than using the typical `millis()` / Blink Without Delay technique (or any of the libraries built around this approach). Most people who ask for “multitasking” would expect to be able to `delay()` a task without blocking the others.

Comment: The second issue is that it makes the tasks run in interrupt context. There are a few traps you have to be careful about with code running in interrupt context, like increased latency to other interrupts, or data races. You most likely can handle them, but they can be a problem for beginners.